# Android button has smaller height than the second button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have in layout two Buttons `btn_later` and `btn_ok`. They should be equal size but now `btn_ok` has smaller height than `btn_later`. How to solve that?

Here is how it looks like (`btn_later` on the left, `btn_ok` on the right):

[image]

Here is my code:

rate_dialog_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/grateful_for_your_rating"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="&#128522;"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view" />



    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/rating_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rating_bar">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_later"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/c_2196f3"
            android:textColor="@color/c_4acfac"

            android:text="@string/later" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:text="@string/rate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:enabled="false" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're setting the first button's background to a solid color:

```
android:background="@color/c_2196f3"
```

This overrides the button's default background which has some intrinsic padding. Try using `backgroundTint` instead:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/c_2196f3"
```